# HTML form inside of PHP include page - Not Working

Tags: php, html

I have a form inside a PHP include page which is included in my index.php -  - Strangely the form will not work when tested in the index.php - however i saved the form to separate HTML file and it works correctly.

What am I doing wrong? Is it the PHP include that is doing this? Please advise - Ty

CODE:

```
        <table class="table1">
        <tr>
        <td><form class="jotform-form" action="http://submit.jotform.co/submit/2367784331/" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img class="imgmove" src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/form/firstname.png")); ?>'></td>
        <td><input id="first_1" name="q1_fullName1[first]" class="inp" maxlength="255" size="12"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img class="imgmove" src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/form/lastname.png")); ?>'></td>
        <td><input id="last_1" name="q1_fullName1[last]" class="inp" maxlength="255" size="14"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img class="imgmove" src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/form/email.png")); ?>'></td>
        <td><input id="input_3" name="q3_email3" class="inp" maxlength="255" size="16"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><img class="imgmove" src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("images/form/phone.png")); ?>'></td>
        <td><input id="input_4" name="q4_phone4" class="inp" size="11" maxlength="12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input style="font-size:160%;display:block;float:left;margin-top:-40px;padding:5px 10px;" type="button" value="Contact Me!" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong?" — Giving the vaguest possible explanation of the problem and not showing us the code. See http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: Hello sorry - im learning - im reading up on the jsFiddle - code is up - thanks for the help every1

Comment: @Truth I am not sure how to use this jsFIddle - and I didn't post the code because I don't see anything wrong with the form - like i said it works when i save it to .HTML but it doesn't work in the PHP include page... So I guessing that PHP is causing the problem somewhere..

Comment: Just an FYI, your markup is invalid. Move the beginning of the form outside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input type should be submit:

```
<input style="font-size:160%;display:block;float:left;margin-top:-40px;padding:5px 10px;" type="submit" value="Contact Me!" />
```

Comment: you are awesome! it's 3am and i been designing/coding for the past 10 hours - im so tired that my eyes are playing tricks on me. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use require in place of include.If the file is not including then it will give a fatal error.
This might help you to solve your problem.

Comment: This file is including fine. Just when i try to use the form -- Nothing happens.